# How to increase performance of PHP curl

Tags: php

Any advise on how to increase performance for the following PHP script? The entire set of code is nested under 2 level foreach with an if clause. It took about 30 seconds to load now.

```
foreach ($result as $_type => &$type_v) {
    foreach ($type_v as $xiaji_id => &$v) {
        if($lvl == 2){
            $beginDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($BeginDatetime));
            $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($EndDatetime));
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/Admin/Report/Detail1?id=" . $v['g_name']. "%2C60900733116476424%2C6007323122&type=1&play=0&item=0&num=&bdate=".$beginDate."&edate=".$endDate."&settle=1&users_json=%5B%5D&ids_json=%5B%5D");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $str=preg_replace("/[\t\n\r]+/","",$output);
            
            $pattern = '/Paid\：<\/span> <span.*?>(.*?)<\/span>/';
            preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
            $totalMatches += $matches[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Does the API server not receive data in bulk?

Comment: Why 2 nested loops? I think if bulk option is available, that would just be a one cURL call with no loops needed at all

Comment: use forks to make your app multithreaded, like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526509/php-fork-limit-childs-in-the-task

Comment: `$lvl` is not declared. Does this `if` make sense?

Comment: I would make the calls async to increase performance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171222/async-curl-request-in-php

Comment: you can use the multi curl functions https://www.php.net/curl_multi_exec

Comment: Yes, the server receive data in bulk. About 300k rows of data, i need to process and get the data beforehand, hence the code have to be nested within the foreach loops.