# How to implement one PHP scheduled job to run separate process in XAMPP?

Tags: php, cron-task

I have a PHP script "cron.php" to run by Task scheduler, which is on Windows 10 (XAMPP PHP 7.4.3). The script calls "process_1.php" and "process_2.php". As shown in code below, the 2nd process will run **ONLY** after the 1st process has completed.

**Is there a way to run both processes concurrently?**

In a browser, I could open two windows then launch 2 processes, and they would run separately and concurrently.

It seems the "include", "cURL", and "exec" all run two processes sequentially, as I tested below individually.

```
<?php
 // cron.php

 // 1st test
    include "process_1.php";
    include "process_2.php";

 // 2nd test
    exec (php.exe -f process_1.php);
    exec (php.exe -f process_1.php);

 // 3rd test
    $curl_obj = new curl_obj ();
    $curl_obj.exec (url='process_1.php');
    $curl_obj.exec (url='process_2.php');

?>
```

I could schedule 2 tasks to run "process_1.php" and "process_2.php" at the same time, to get exactly what I expect, in this way I don't even need "cron.php". But I am looking for a better solution. Otherwise, I will have to schedule 100 tasks if I have 100 processes. I hope one scheduled job could take care of all processes.

**The benefit is time saving**. Say each process takes 1 hour to complete, in cron job it will take 2 hours when running sequentially.  If I could split them into 2 process running concurrently in scheduled job, it does not need two hours.  When I had both processes running on separate browsers concurrently, it took 65 minutes to complete both.

So far I got to know following as possible solutions, and I will try them.  Thank you for all responses!

- Thread
- Parallel
- curl_multi_exec

Thank you!

Comment: are you running all the processes 3 times? or these are only examples

Comment: `Is there a way to run both processes concurrently?`...maybe put them in two separate PHP scripts and have two separate scheduled tasks which trigger at the same time. `I am looking for a better solution`...define "better". `I will have to schedule 100 tasks if I have 100 processes`...or you'll have to write `exec` 100 times in your PHP code. Unless...you have a database with a list of the functions you want to run, and loop them. But realistically, your CPU can't run 100 jobs completely simultaneously anyway...what exactly are you all these 100 in-parallel processes supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Flash Thunder The code shows how I tested  3 times by different methods. Thank you!

Comment: @ADyson Sorry it was exaggerate to say 100 jobs. Let me say just two. As explanation added, I'd like to save time when both processes are running currently. Thank you!

Comment: If you only have two, then by far the simplest way is to have two scheduled tasks.

Comment: On windows it would be tricky, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications , on linux you could use forks like in this answer-o-question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526509/php-fork-limit-childs-in-the-task

Comment: @Flash Thunder 
Reading the url on windows, I am afraid it's probably not what I am looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: @Markus Zeller Thank you for heads up!  Yeah, that is the correct direction.  However, I was unable to make it work, for the "Class 'Thread' not found". Further research brought me *parallel*. Looking at the demo at https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel, which shows pound and dot printed alternately, I know that is exactly what I have been trying to get.

Comment: @trashycat I gave exactly the same link that Markus Zeller did... :/

Comment: @Flash Thunder My apologies!  I opened quite several tabs on stackoverflow yesterday, and probably I mistakenly thought another URL was from you. You deserve the credit :-)